# Data recovery from Galaxy S3 that will not turn on

Tags: samsung, internal-storage, samsung-galaxy-s-3, data-recovery

I have an old Galaxy S3 which hasn't been in regular use for at least five years, but which I know has some data on it that I would like to retrieve. However, the phone will not power on, even while plugged in through USB. The battery is relatively new and has been fully charged using an external charger. The power button on the phone is still clicky. When I plug the phone into my computer by USB, a red LED on the phone turns on for about a minute, then goes off. My computer (Win 10) recognizes that a USB device as been connected (Qualcomm HS-USB QDLoader 9008), but I can't access data without powering on the phone (or in any case, I don't know *how* to access data without powering on the phone).

Is there a way to get the data off the internal memory without power to the phone? I have no desire to actually use this phone, I just want the data, so dismantling the thing is absolutely on the table.

Comment: If long pressing the power button (10 to 60 seconds) does not change the device behavior from my perspective the only chance is replacing the battery and other hardware components unless the phone boots up again.

Comment: https://youtu.be/OY7OlY0OW2Q